# How to step through only certain packages in IntelliJ debugger

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, functional-programming

I'm debugging implementation with heavy use of method references. Indirection is used to enable logging and error handling aspects around module executions.

It's easy to *step into* referenced method using debugger, but *stepping out* back to call site is cumbersome. The stack contains a lot of proxy classes and aspects between call site and method under execution as shown in this image

[image]

Is it possible to configure *step into* and *step out* functions to skip classes not belonging to certain package? I know it's possible to use class filters on breakpoints, but I would need familiar feature with step functions.

Answer (score 3):

In the Intellij Idea there is quite a lot of tweaking in `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Stepping`. Make sure you check the `Always do smart step into` option. The option `Skip synthetic methods` may be what you need, you can also configure to skip some packages. More documentation here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/stepping-through-the-program.html#smart-step-into